# Parse LogIn and SignUp Func SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

So the problem I have been having is that I am watching Tutorials and when the put in the line of codes I have below it automatically makes it a function. For me when I type it in all I get is

```
logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername: String!, password: String!)
```

That is not a function. So I try to make it a a function by adding func to the start and {} at the ends ( Look below)

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername: String!, password: String!){

    }
```

That all works fine however when I add the next one (look below)

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser: PFUser!){

    }
```

I get an error "Definition Conflicts with Previous Value", am I able to just change the name of the function and everything will be alright? Because In the video, I watched they didn't need to change the name.

So how can I get this to work, without Errors.

Here is all the code in case

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI



class homeViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {







//These are all Buttons--------------
@IBAction func emailB(sender: UIButton) {
    println("Email View : Pressed : Working")

}


@IBAction func EstimatorB(sender: UIButton) {
    println("Estimator View : Pressed : Working")
    let viewEstimator: AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EstimatorScreen")
    viewEstimator
}
//====================================

//Login Screen Pop-up-----------------
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil){

        var LogInViewController : PFLogInViewController! = PFLogInViewController()


        LogInViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController! = PFSignUpViewController()

        signUpViewController.delegate = self

        LogInViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController

        self.presentViewController(LogInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
//=======================================






//To go to another screen
//let viewHome = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeScreen")

// IGNOR THIS CODE-------=======================
 func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//MARK : Login 
    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername: String!, password: String!){

    }

     func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser: PFUser!){

    }

     func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError: NSError!){

    }


//MArK : SignUp

     func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, shouldBeginSignUp: [NSObject : AnyObject]){

    }

     func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser: PFUser){

    }

    func  signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didFailToSignUpWithError: NSError?){

    }







}

}
```

Comment: I copied all of the code into a sample project (I made sure I had all of the frameworks installed). When I changed the name of the functions, all of those syntax errors went away. I'm not sure why this is giving errors though initially because you can use method overloading in swift so long as the parameters are different i believe. Maybe the problem here is that the parameters have some of the same arguments and parameter types.

Comment: okie, believe I fixed it, I have another problem though, func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername: String!, password: String!){

    }   it will pick up password if i type that in however if I type in username it cant find it

Comment: The password should be passed as a parameter when you call that function then the parameter name should be used to sign the user in. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by " if i type that in however if I type in username it cant find it"

Comment: I was able to figure it out, parse is not properly implementing methods

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do without the head ache of parse making your login/signup for you...here is a great tutorial that walks your through step by step on making your own custom one. its pretty simple.
i ended up not using theirs because of all the errors it kept giving me.
https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-part-3-sign-up-sign-in-sign-out-security-349adc94ef0e

Answer (score 0):

I had my swift file set up just like yours but I would recommend that you go the route of a custom login because A) You have more control and B) it is surprisingly super simple and does not take much time. Also I assume you are a parse beginner and the method I suggested will make you understand better how login/signup works.